# Reference a part of external JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

Good afternoon. Google doesn't seem to have a lot of information on this, but I just wanted to make sure before I try to do it manually!

Is it possible to reference another JSON file (ex: /src/schema.json) but only a specific part of it?

For example, schema.json:

```
{
   "Properties": {
      "Cats": {
      ..
      },
      "Dogs": {
      ..
      }
}
```

Is there a way to only reference the "Dogs" part and not the whole JSON file?

Thanks!

Comment: no. json isn't a "streamable" format. json is either parsed in its entirety, or it's not parsed at all.

Comment: The typical solution would be to grab the entire file, parse the entire file, and then refer to only the parts you need. Why do you need to do this? For speed? Are the file(s) so large that you're worried that your parser may run out of memory when creating the object?

Comment: That said, there is no theoretical reason why you couldn't write a parser to do this. The entire document *would* need to be parsed (or at least, the entire document until the end of the desired property value), but you could theoretically write a parser that chose not to return results (nor allocate memory) for any part of the document except the part you're interested in. *That* said, writing you're own parser is a lot of work for a general problem that's already been solved very well by lots of of people already. If you're dead-set on writing your own for some reason, you *could* do it.

Comment: you could index the json and do a partial fetch (http Range) on the segment that contains your definitions. Since JSON is without refs, having just that chuck of source text will result in the exact same object as parsing the whole thing and drilling down to the object....

Answer (score 0):

lets say we store/set your json in a variable

Example..

```
 var pets = {
       "Properties": {
          "Cats": {

          },
          "Dogs": {
          name: 'Tommy';
          }
    }
 }
```

This is how you would access "Dogs" ...which is practical

```
pets.Properties.Dogs.name;
```

Output should be:

```
Tommy
```